# iFrame not working - turns up blank

Tags: html, iframe

In a random experiment, I wanted to display a Ruby app I'm running on another server via an iframe.

```
<html>

<body>
<iframe src="http://192.155.83.120:5000/r/2" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

No luck, turns up blank.

Is there something in the code of the ruby app that prevents it from showing up properly in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframe will supports only the exact path of the file name... like

```
<iframe src="http://192.155.83.120:5000/r/2/index.html" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Really? I've tried something without a file name and it seems to work - <iframe src="http://thee-roundtable.com" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>

Comment: <iframe src="http://thee-roundtable.com"; width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>  - is the domain name.. so, it automatically call the index file... now you are trying some path under domain... so, it wont work...

Comment: and one more thing is there... i think [http://192.155.83.120:5000/r/2/] is not have index.html file...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I wonder if there's any way to get 192.155.83.120:5000/r/2 to work under an index.html or something. Thanks for the FYI :)